# Windows Store App Custom Control

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, custom-controls

I need some help about my custom control. So shortly I have somthing like this in Generic.xaml:

```
<MyCustomControl_A>

  <MyCustomControl_B />

</MyCustomControl_A>
```

I want to access part of the properties of CustomControl_B in its OnApplyTemplate method, but problem is that this method not firing. Please give me some ideas about what can be the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get acces to any elements in "User control" by name (x:name = "MyB").

OnApplyTemplate method called only for "Templated Control" after overriding default style in constructor (this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomControl1))